# DateTime value from Oracle to MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, oracle

I have a question, how to parse `datetime` value from Oracle to MySQL database.

I wrote this to extract a datetime from Oracle:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(p1.creation_date,'DD.MM.RRRR HH24:mi:ss') AS dat_pot 
FROM TABLE
```

then I put the result into data set, then I extract the value of date from dataset like this:

```
string lDat_otp = null;        

if (rw_mat["dat_otp"].ToString().Length <= 0)
{
   lDat_otp = "0";
}
else
{
   lDat_otp = "convert(datetime,'" + rw_mat["dat_otp"] + "',4)";
}
```

Then I use `lDat_otp` in `INSERT` statement with some other values like this:

```
myQuery = " INSERT INTO ordersstavke (BrDok, " +
          " SifParFil, SifParIsp, DatPriOtpr, SifPodKla, Masa, Paketa) " +
          " VALUES ('" + rw_mat["brdok"] + "', '" +
                         rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] + "','" +
                         rw_mat["partner"] + "'," +
                         lDat_otp + ",'" +
                         rw_det["ibrmat"] + "', '" +
                         rw_det["izlaz_tez"] + "', '" +
                         rw_det["izlaz_kol"] + "')";
```

But there is an error on execute and it goes:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '26.01.2012 13:48:41',4)','100654', '0', '10')' at line 1

So help!!!

Comment: Ok thanks, I am sorry about this, I'm nwe, will keep in mind in the future for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the datetime field into a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) struct and then create an `insert into` query with parameters and pass the date as parameter :

```
DateTime time = //Some value ...
String myQuery = " INSERT INTO ordersstavke (BrDok, " +
          " SifParFil, SifParIsp, DatPriOtpr, SifPodKla, Masa, Paketa) " +
          " VALUES ('" + rw_mat["brdok"] + "', '" +
                         rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] + "','" +
                         rw_mat["partner"] + "'," +
                         "?date ,'" +
                         rw_det["ibrmat"] + "', '" +
                         rw_det["izlaz_tez"] + "', '" +
                         rw_det["izlaz_kol"] + "')";
MysqlCommand command = new MysqlCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?date", time);
```

Doing this you should not have problems with date formatting.
*I strongly suggest to use  parameters instead of string concatenation even for the others parameters of the query ...*

Comment: I wrote this DateTime lDat_otp = rw_mat["dat_otp"].ToString().Length <= 0 ? DateTime.MinValue : DateTime.ParseExact(rw_mat["dat_otp"].ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); but in mysql database in datetime field i got this '0000-00-00 00:00:00 is it problem with formatting?

Comment: What is the value of the time field when you pass it to the parameter ?

Comment: The value is  DatPriOtpr = 26.1.2012. 13:48:41

Comment: Nope, the same, the datetime field in mysql is in this format: 0000-00-00 00:00:00, maybe I have to force that kind of date from Oracle

Comment: This works for me: 1.Extract date from oracle data base and pass it to variable

 string lDat_otp = "";

  if (rw_mat["dat_otp"].ToString().Length <= 0)
      {
         lDat_otp = "";
      }
      else
      {
          lDat_otp = rw_mat["dat_otp"].ToString();
      }

2.Conversion to mysql format

DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(lDat_otp); string formatForMySql = dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

3.Pass formatForMySql variable to procedure or to something else